# Updating XML with HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Is it possible to create a form in html that will directly edit, add or delete an XML file. for example if I have an xml page with country, state and city, is it possible to make a form that you can add to the country, then to the state and then to the city, and also can you add to one sub category such as adding another state and city to a pre-existing country. If this is all possible please point me towards the right direction, I am also looking to complete this in Javascript and HTML, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System)

**BUT**, MDN specifies that:

*This is an experimental technology
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.*

I think that this work must be do the server, not the client.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Awesome! But is there another way to do the update rather than messing with the server, All within the HTML form and the javascript, I am trying to make it so that users who don't know how to code can add inforamtion to the xml file like new cities or new states within a certain country

Comment: In the client you can generate a xml code, but must exist a server to save this code in a file, to persist data. @user3773023